# Graphicsmagick C++ API

Tags: c++, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I want to use the C++ API for `graphicsmagick`

I need to convert image data directly from `OpenCV` and use `graphicsmagick` to save the file as `tiff` with group 4 compression

The command line

```
gm convert input -type bilevel -monochrome -compress group4 output.tif
```

Could anyone provide some code (see the above command line) to simply convert the output from `OpenCV` to `tiff` with group 4 compression

I'm new to C++ :)

## testing graphicsmagick

I'm trying to make `graphicsmagick` work. Found a very simple code in the docs

I can't find `Magick++.h`

`locate /Magick++.h` returns nothing

but graphicsmagick is installed

```
# gm -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.20 2014-08-16 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
```

## code

```
/*
 *  Compile
 *  g++ gm_test.cpp -o gm_test `GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
 */

#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Image image( "100x100", "white" );
    image.pixelColor( 49, 49, "red" );
    image.write( "red_pixel.png" );
    return 0;
}
```

## compile

```
# g++ gm_test.cpp -o gm_test `GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
-bash: GraphicsMagick++-config: command not found
gm_test.cpp:6:22: fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Magick++.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 5):

**Updated Answer**

Try looking for a file called `GraphicsMagick-config` under the directory where you installed GraphicsMagick like this:

```
find /usr -name "GraphicsMagick-config"
```

When you find that, you can ask it to tell you the compiler include flags and linker flags like this:

```
/usr/some/path/GraphicsMagick-config --cflags --libs
```

Then you can compile with:

```
gcc $(/usr/some/path/GraphicsMagick-config --cflags --libs) somefile.c -o somefile
```

**Original Answer**

Look in the directory where you installed GraphicsMagick for a file ending in `.pc`, which is the `pkg-config` file, e.g.

```
find /usr/local -iname "graphic*.pc"
```

Then pass this file to `pkg-config` to get the CFLAGS and LIBS you should use for compiling. So, if your `graphicsmagick.pc` is in `/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.23/lib/pkgconfig/GraphicsMagick.pc`, use:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.23/lib/pkgconfig/GraphicsMagick.pc
```

which will give you this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.23/lib/pkgconfig/GraphicsMagick.pc
-I/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.23/include/GraphicsMagick -L/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.23/lib -lGraphicsMagick
```

Then you would compile with:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs somefile.c -o somefile
```

Comment: `find /usr/local -name "graphic*.pc"` doesn't find anything

Comment: Sorry, try with `-iname` in place of `-name` so it is case-insensitive.

Comment: `find /usr/local -iname "graphic*.pc"` still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's helpful, last day i have the same error :no magick++.h when i compile ImageMagick (not graphicsmagick).
   so i follows the steps in a official website to reinstall ImageMagick and finally i succeed.web:

1 http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php
  2 http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php

i download the latest source code(ImageMagick6.9) in centOS-6.5
   and then ./configure, make, make install.
   i hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu the `GraphicsMagick++-config` program you are using to get compile flags is correctly part of the same package which includes Magick++.h. Trying to run it tell you where to find it:

```
$ g++ gm_test.cpp -o gm_test `GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
The program 'GraphicsMagick++-config' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
gm_test.cpp:6:22: fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
```

compilation terminated.

So do what it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
```

Try the compile again and you will get a different error because `GraphicsMagick++-config` is linking to an uninstalled and unneeded library:

```
$ g++ gm_test.cpp -o gm_test `GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You can manually specify the libs and the compile and link works:

```
$ g++ gm_test.cpp -o gm_test -I/usr/include/GraphicsMagick -Wall -g -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -pthread  -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick -ljbig
$ ./gm_test
```

Or you can install the required library:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev
```